# Using ExternalEvaluate within ParallelDo

Tags: parallelization, interoperability, python

I have had great success using Python in Mathematica (for some computations for which there are very well optimised Python packages but not for Mathematica). I have some Mathematica functions that are calls of Python functions, similar to the example given in Applications section of this page: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExternalEvaluate.html.

I would now like to run these functions within a ParallelDo function, unfortunately  it isn't working. Here is a MWE and the output:

```
session = StartExternalSession["Python-NumPy"];
ExternalEvaluate[session, "def double(x):
    return x*2"];
doublePython[arg_] := ExternalEvaluate[session, "double(" <> ToString[arg] <> ")"]

Do[Pause[1]; Print[doublePython[i]], {i, Range[4]}] // AbsoluteTiming
ParallelDo[Pause[1]; Print[doublePython[i]], {i, Range[4]}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: MWE output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For these sorts of objects you can create a session per kernel.  Ideally you would want separate Python session per kernel to prevent one parallel process from being blocked by another when the [`ExternalEvaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExternalEvaluate.html) calls are being made. More can be found in the [Parallel Computing Tools User Guide](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ParallelTools/tutorial/Overview.html).

Launch the kernels

```
LaunchKernels[]
```

Create a Python instance on each kernel and setup the environment.

```
ParallelEvaluate[
 session = StartExternalSession["Python-NumPy"];
 ExternalEvaluate[session, "def double(x):
      return x*2"];
 ]
```

Now you may run your process in parallel.

```
ParallelDo[Pause[1]; 
  Print[doublePython[i]], {i, Range[4]}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Clean up with

```
ParallelEvaluate[DeleteObject[session]]
CloseKernels[]
```

Hope this helps.